# Search for GitHub repos which have certain package.json dependencies

Tags: github

I want to search for public GitHub repos (and hopefully sort them by a star) that have certain `package.json` dependencies like `next-mdx-enhanced`, `@tailwindcss/typography`, and `typescript`.

I can get [all repos](https://github.com/hashicorp/next-mdx-enhanced/network/dependents?package_id=UGFja2FnZS00MDU5NTI1ODA%3D) which use `next-mdx-enhanced` by visiting [`next-mdx-enhanced`](https://github.com/hashicorp/next-mdx-enhanced) repo and clicking on `Used by xxx` i.e. dependency graph.

Similar for [tailwindcss-typography](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-typography).
So, how can I get repos containing a combination of these dependencies?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try filtering all GitHub repositories with a package.json file with a keyword like this: next-mdx-enhanced filename:package.json. [Here is an example](https://github.com/search?q=next-mdx-enhanced+filename%3Apackage.json&type=Code)

Comment: your link returns zero results.

Comment: that worked! sometime need to add quotes to get exact matches https://github.com/search?p=2&q=%22next-mdx-enhanced%22+%22%40tailwindcss%2Ftypography%22+filename%3Apackage.json&type=Code

Comment: This is great. Is there a way to do a more targeted search for a string that containing special characters? For example, say I want to find this specific dependency in all package.json files: `"some-dependency": "^1.2.3"`? I haven't found a way to get that to work.

Answer (score 0):

Put these in Github Search box:

- To search for repos that have `library A` and `library B`:

`"react-markdown" AND "react-syntax-highlighter" path:**/package.json`

[search results](https://github.com/search?q=%22react-markdown%22+AND+%22react-syntax-highlighter%22+path%3A**%2Fpackage.json&type=code)

- To search for repos that have an exact library version, ex:  `"react-markdown":"^9.0.1"`

`"\"react-markdown\": \"^9.0.1\"" path:**/package.json`

[search results](https://github.com/search?q=%22%5C%22react-markdown%5C%22%3A+%5C%22%5E9.0.1%5C%22%22+path%3A**%2Fpackage.json&type=code)

---

For more info refer Github search syntax guide: https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/github-code-search/understanding-github-code-search-syntax#using-qualifiers

Answer (score -1):

To search repos that have:

Gemfile dependency:
https://github.com/search?q=gemfile+in%3Areadme

package.json dependency:
https://github.com/search?q=package.json+in%3Areadme

requirements.txt:
https://github.com/search?q=requirements.txt+in%3Areadme

To find packages owned by a certain user or organization, use the user or org qualifier.

```
user:USERNAME
```

user:codertocat matches packages owned by @codertocat

```
org:ORGNAME
```

org:github matches packages owned by the GitHub organization

Comment: that's not what I asked. Please read the question